# How to check a nil value of Pointer to struct net.IPNet in Golang

Tags: go

How can I check the nil value as a result of the assignment of variable b below?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)


type Subnet struct {
    ID                int
    IP                *net.IPNet
}

func main() {
    var s = Subnet{
        ID: 12345,
        IP: &net.IPNet{
            IP:   net.IP{10, 1, 232, 0},
            Mask: net.IPMask{255, 255, 255, 0},
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", s)
    var b = Subnet{
        ID: 12345,
        IP: &net.IPNet{},
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", b)
    if b.IP == nil {
        fmt.Println("hello there")
    }
}
```

Here is the go playground https://play.golang.org/p/Jk6_3ofyH5

Basically, I expect that "hello there" will be printed out as b.IP is nil, but it did not.

Comment: Thats because `b.IP` isn't nil.

Comment: so what is the real value of b.IP? printing it out as in the playground showed that its value is nil. Pardon that I am a Go newbie.

Comment: The output is misleading. You set it to a pointer to an default-initialized `net.IPNet` three lines above the check: `IP: &net.IPNet{}`

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're confusing *the value* `nil` with a concept called "zero value".

#### The zero value

Any type in Go — no matter whether standard or created by the user —
has a "zero value" which is the value assigned automatically to any variable of that type which was not explicitly initialized otherwise.
IOW, when you have

```
type T …

var v T
```

the value of the variable "v" will be the zero value of type `T`.

The concept of the zero value follows naturally from the Go's property
of not allowing uninitialized variables: variables in Go always have
sensible values (contraty to say, C).

#### The `nil` value

A special value, `nil`, which is a predeclared identifier in Go,
is the zero value for a set of *types which have reference semantics.*

The term "reference semantics" might be intimidating but it can be
explained pretty simply: a type has reference semantics when variables of
it *reference* some data structure instead of directly containing it.
Hence when you copy the value of a variable of such type into another
variable, both variables reference the same data structure.

As you should know, maps, slices, interfaces, function values, and pointers have reference semantics in Go, and that's why their zero values are `nil`.

#### The distinction

The major takeaway to draw from the above is that `nil` is the zero value
for some types which have a certain property, but not for all of them.

For example, for

```
type T struct {
  A int
  B string
}
```

the zero value is

```
T{
  A: 0,
  B: "",
}
```

that is, a value of type `T` having its fields initialized
to the zero values corresponding to the types of those fields:
0 for `int` and "" for `string`.

#### Your particular problem

In your type

```
type Subnet struct {
    ID int
    IP *net.IPNet
}
```

the field "IP" has a pointer type `*net.IPNet`, which is a pointer
to (or, we may say, an address of) a value of the type `net.IPNet`.
Hence its zero value is `nil`.

Now if you were to declare something like

```
var subnet Subnet
```

this variable would start its life initialized to the zero value
of its type, and that would mean that its field "IP"
would have the zero value for its type, `nil`.

In your example, you do:

```
var b = Subnet{
    ID: 12345,
    IP: &net.IPNet{},
}
```

and that means creating a variable "b" initialized to a particular
value defined by the *literal* placed on the right hand of the
assignment operator `=`.

The field "IP" in that literal is *not* initialized to the zero value
of its type; instead, it's initialized to a pointer containing the
address of an *anonymous variable* wihch has the type `net.IPNet`
and containing the zero value of that type.

To say this in different words, the result it roughly equivalent
to the following:

```
var ip net.IPNet

var b = Subnet{
    ID: 12345,
    IP: &ip,
}
```

There, the variable "ip" contains the zero value of its type,
and the variable "b.IP" contains a pointer to the variable "ip".

Since that field "IP" points to *some real memory location,*
its value is obviosly not `nil`, which makes a value of a type having
refence semantics "point to nowhere",
and that's why the test in your `if` statement fails.

Answer (score 1):

The check should be like,
    
    `if b.IP != nil {
        fmt.Println("hello there")
    }`

And the output will have hello-world,

{ID:12345 IP:10.1.232.0/24}
{ID:12345 IP:}
hello there

Note:Golang's nil is not same as Cpp's NULL, it is the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

`nil` is a [predeclared identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers) in Go. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

type Subnet struct {
    ID int
    IP *net.IPNet
}

func main() {
    var b = Subnet{ID: 1, IP: nil}
    fmt.Println(b.IP == nil)
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/-745-hhLGg

Answer (score 1):

Notice that `IPNet` has *[`String() string`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPNet.String) function* which makes it implements [`Stringer` interface](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer). Basically this function provides custom string representation of the struct when the struct is printed. If you dig in further to [the source code](https://golang.org/src/net/ip.go?s=12087:12118#L484) you'll see that this function returns string `"<nil>"` when either `IPNet.IP` or `IPNet.Mask` is nil. This explained how your code prints `<nil>` when the value of `Subnet.IP` field is actually not `nil`.

Now to answer the question in the title literally, you already did the check correctly by comparing the value with `nil`. In addition, you can try to print using `%#v` instead, for example :

```
func main() {
    var b = Subnet{ID: 12345, IP: &net.IPNet{}}
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", b)
    fmt.Printf("is null: %t\n", b.IP == nil)
    var c = Subnet{ID: 12345, IP: nil}
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", c)
    fmt.Printf("is null: %t", c.IP == nil)
}
```

**<kbd>[`playground`](https://play.golang.org/p/yxoBRHVH6c)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
main.Subnet{ID:12345, IP:(*net.IPNet)(0x10444340)}
is null: false
main.Subnet{ID:12345, IP:(*net.IPNet)(nil)}
is null: true
```

Comment: There is open issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/39516 about this `<nil>` output being misleading.